# Finding the minimal monic polynomial given a root

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, minimal-polynomials

Given $z = \sqrt[3]{7} + \sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{R}$ a root, compute its minimal monic polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Is there a clever way to do this without having to compute $z^2$, $z^3$, $z^4$, $z^5$ and $z^6$?

Comment: Consider $ (z- \sqrt{5}) ^3 = 7$.

Comment: @CalvinLin I do not quite follow. This seems to give the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. Is there an easy way to upgrade this to find the minimal polynomial over the rationals (probably I am just too tired to see the trick)?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Expand that, shift $\sqrt{5}$ terms to one side, and square again.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks!

Comment: @CalvinLin This was helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=\sqrt[3]{7}+\sqrt{5}$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
z=\sqrt[3]{7}+\sqrt{5}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
z-\sqrt{5}=\sqrt[3]{7}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(z-\sqrt{5})^3=7
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
z^3-3z^2\sqrt{5}+15z-5\sqrt{5}=7
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
z^3+15z-7=(3z^2+5)\sqrt{5}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(z^3+15z-7)^2=\bigl((3z^2+5)\sqrt{5}\bigr)^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
z^6+30z^4-14z^3+225z^2-210z+49
=
45z^4+150z^2+125
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
z^6-15z^4-14z^3+75z^2-210z-76=0
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $z$ is a root of the polynomial
$$
x^6-15x^4-14x^3+75x^2-210x-76
$$
To show that the above polynomial is actually the *minimal* monic polynomial for $z$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, we can argue as follows . . .

By the rational root test, the polynomials $x^3-7$ and $x^2-5$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, hence we get
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7}):\mathbb{Q}]=3
\;\;\text{and}\;\;
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}]=2
$$
Now let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7},\sqrt{5})$.

Then from
$$
[K:\mathbb{Q}]=[K:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7}):\mathbb{Q}]
$$
we get that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ is a multiple of $3$, and from
$$
[K:\mathbb{Q}]=[K:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}]
$$
we get that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ is a multiple of $2$.

Hence $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ is a multiple of $6$, so $[K:\mathbb{Q}]\ge 6$.

But then from
$$
K
=
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7},\sqrt{5})
=
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})(\sqrt{5})
$$
we get
\begin{align*}
&
[K:\mathbb{Q}]
\\[4pt]
=\;&
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})(\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}]
\\[4pt]
=\;&
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})(\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7}):\mathbb{Q}]
\\[4pt]
=\;&
3[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})(\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})]
\\[4pt]
\le\;&
3{\,\cdot\,}2
\\[4pt]
=\;&
6
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and then, since we already have $[K:\mathbb{Q}]\ge 6$, we get $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=6$.

Now let $F=\mathbb{Q}(z)$.

From $z=\sqrt[3]{7}+\sqrt{5}$, we get $z\in K$, hence $F\subseteq K$.

But from the equation
$$
z^3+15z-7=(3z^2+5)\sqrt{5}
$$
we get
$$
\sqrt{5}
=
\frac
{z^3+15z-7}
{3z^2+5}
$$
so $\sqrt{5}\in F$.

Then since $\sqrt[3]{7}=z-\sqrt{5}$, we get $\sqrt[3]{7}\in F$.

Since $\sqrt{5}\in F$ and $\sqrt[3]{7}\in F$, it follows that $K\subseteq F$.

Then, since we already have the inclusion $F\subseteq K$, we get $F=K$, so
$
[F:\mathbb{Q}]
=
[K:\mathbb{Q}]
=
6
$.

From $[F:\mathbb{Q}]=6$, it follows that
$$
x^6-15x^4-14x^3+75x^2-210x-76
$$
is the minimal monic polynomial for $z$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: You didn't prove that it is *minimal*. In any case this is a PSQ and a dupe of many prior questions so should not have been answered.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: I've edited in a proof of minimality.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to calculate using galios group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt[3]{7})$, Suppose that the Galios group is $G = \{\sigma \mid automorphisms\}$, then look at the orbit of $z =\sqrt{5} + \sqrt[3]{7}$  under $G$, that will be all the conjugates of $z$, using all the conjugates we get the minimal polynomial of $z$

Comment: It is not clear to me how "using the conjugates, we get the minimal polynomial." Also, doesn't one generally need the minimal polynomial on hand to compute the Galois group?